# How to sketch $\ln|\sin x|$

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

The question is to find the number of solutions of
$$\ln|\sin x|=-x^2+2x$$ but I just don't know how to sketch a logarithmic function like $\ln|\sin x|$.

A step by step method would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let https://www.desmos.com/calculator sketch the graph for you.

Comment: @GerryMyerson graphing calculators are not allowed in my tests, unfortunately.

Comment: Is posting your test questions to math.stackexchange allowed?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Should have said it better , I'm preparing for a test sir. we are not allowed to use graphing calculators. we have to sketch it roughly , But I don't know how to sketch this function

Comment: OK. So, first, there's no need to sketch the graph of $y=\log|\sin x|$ if the question is to find the number of solutions of $\log|\sin x|=-x^2+2x$. But if you do want to sketch the graph anyway, you can look at the sketch desmos (or any graphing software) makes and learn from it. You can ask yourself why the graph has this or that property, and if you can work that out you might get a better understanding of how to sketch it on your own.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thank you great idea, will do. Why is there no need to sketch the graph, sir?

Comment: Does the question say to sketch the graph? No! So, if the question doesn't say to sketch the graph, then there's no need to sketch the graph. The answer you accepted doesn't include a sketch of the graph, so doesn't that mean that you agree that there's no need to sketch the graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are looking for solutions to $\sin{x} = \pm e^{-x^{2}+2x}$.

Now, (just taking one part of the right hand side), the graph of $e^{-x^{2}+2x}$ approaches $0$ as $x \to \infty$, so the graph of $y=\sin{x}$ will intersect the graph of $y=e^{-x^{2}+2x}$ infinitely many times. This will give infinitely many solutions to $\ln{|\sin{x}|} = -x^{2}+2x$.

Comment: sir what if an interval is given?

Comment: Then use the fact that you can sketch a rough graph of $\pm e^{-x^{2}+2x}$ and of $\sin{x}$ on an interval, count the number of intersections.

Comment: Sir in the graph there is a hump how would I predict that?

Comment: 1: by using the fact that $e^{x}$ is an increasing function, so larger inputs will give larger outputs, or 2: by looking at the derivative to see where $e^{-x^{2}+2x}$ will have a local maximum

Answer (score 3):

First you draw $y=|\sin x|$ which is nothing else that the graph of the sine with negative part mirrored wrt $x$-axis.

Then remember that sine function is less than $1$. Logarithm of numbers in $(0,1)$ are negative ($\ln 1=0$ so at $x=\pi/2$ logarithm is zero), and that $\ln x\to -\infty$ as $x\to 0^+$ and get the graph of $y=\ln|\sin x|$.

Finally draw the parabola $y=-x^2+2x$ and see where the two curves intersect in the interval $[0,\pi]$:$x_1\approx 2$ and $x_2\approx 3$.

There are infinitely many solutions
$$2 x-x^2=\log (\left| \sin x\right| )$$
$$|\sin x |=e^{2x-x^2}$$
$$\sin x=\pm e^{2x-x^2}$$

For the limitation on $\sin$ we must have $e^{2 x-x^2}\leq 1\to 2x-x^2\leq 0\to x\le 0\lor x\geq 2$

---

$$...$$

[image]

Comment: But these curves will intersect at lots of other places too. I think this answers nicely the question "How can we find (some of) the solutions", but not the question "how many solutions are there?" (which I believe they are asking)

Comment: @MorganRodgers I swear that I read $[0,\pi]$ somewhere!

Comment: @MorganRodgers Thank you for the remark

Answer (score 0):

If you use inspection, you would notice that, if
$$f(x)=\log (|\sin (x)|)+x^2-2 x$$
$$f\left(\frac{2 \pi }{3}\right)=\log \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)+\frac{4 \pi ^2}{9}-\frac{4 \pi }{3}$$ is very small $(\approx 0.054)$ while
$$f\left(\frac{ \pi }{2}\right)=\frac{1}{4} (\pi -4) \pi \approx -0.674$$
$$f\left(\frac{3 \pi }{4}\right)=\frac{1}{16} \left(-24 \pi +9 \pi ^2-8 \log (2)\right) \approx 0.493$$

On the other hand, there is a problem on each side of $x=n\pi$ because of the logarithm.

So, an infinite number of roots $(\sim 2, n\pi-\epsilon,n\pi+\epsilon)$